# Setting Hibernate Logging Provider with Version 6.1

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, jboss, slf4j

I am using Hibernate 6.1.2. I'd like to log use the default JDK logging provider. [According to a documentation for 5.4](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/topical/html_single/logging/Logging.html), this can be done like this:

```
public class TestSL4JBug {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("org.jboss.logging.provider", "jdk");
        jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myPersistence");        
    }
}
```

I looked for a similar explanation in newer documentations, but I did not find it.

Alas, if I am testing the minimal example above, I get this:

...

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
MLog initialization issue: slf4j found no binding or threatened to use its (dangerously silent) NOPLogger. We consider the slf4j library not found.
```

...

To me, this looks like Hibernate tries to load SLF4J and fails. I have, of course, found guides that say I should add the SLF4J dependency, but that is not what I want.

So my question is: How do I configure Hibernate 6.1.2 to log with JDK logging? Has the property changed, or should I use a better way to set it?

Comment: You need to add the slf4j binding to the jdk logger, may I ask why you don't want to "add the slf4j dependency"?

Comment: I never add a dependency if I can prevent it. In theory, I would need to fully code review everything I add (compare Software Engineering by Ian Sommerville). To me it seems like nobody does it, but the least thing I can do is keep additional packages as low as feasible. I need Hibernate, I cannot omit JBoss Logging, but according to the documentation, I can omit SLF4J. Of course, that is an older version, which is why I am asking.

Comment: I think you're getting this message because slf4j is on your classpath, so you want to omit it but you already seem to be using it, albeit without any binding

Comment: So far I can just say you are correct - I will update once I have found which dependency is loading it.

Comment: slf4j (the API) is pretty hard to avoid these days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that it was not vanilla Hibernate that caused the error. I am also using hibernate-spatial and consequently geolatte-geom. That one is not using JBoss logging and instead always goes through SLF4J. So even though Hibernate went through JDK logging, SLF4J was still loaded. I have now unhappily added slf4j-jdk14 and the error is gone. It's still more layers and source code sources than I am happy with, but probably a lot less than in other programming ecosystems.